# Need to compare 2 variables, each coming from a separate data set, and flag differences

Tags: sql, substring, sas, subset

I have 2 SAS data sets, `Lab` and `Rslt`. They both have all of the same variables, but `Rslt` is supposed to have what is essentially a subset of `Lab`. For what I'm trying to do, there are 4 important variables: `visit`, `accsnnum`, `battrnam`, and `lbtestcd`. All are character variables. I want to compare the two files Lab and Rslt to find out where they vary -- specifically, I need to know the count of `lbtestcd` per unique `accsnnum`.

But I must control for a few factors. First, I only need to compare observations that have "Lipid Panel" or "Chemistry (6)" in the `battrnam` variable. The Rslt file only contains these observations, so we don't need to worry about that one. So I subsetted `Lab` using this code:

```
data work.lab;
  set  livingston.ndb_lab_1;
  where battrnam contains "Lipid Panel" or battrnam = "Chemisty (6)";
run;
```

This worked fine. Now, I need to control for the variable visit. I need to get rid of all observations in both Lab and Rslt that have visits that contain "Day 1" or "Screening". I accomplished this using the following code:

```
data work.lab;
set work.lab;
if visit = "Day 1" or visit = "Screening" then delete;
else visit = visit;
run;

data work.rslt;
set work.rslt;
if visit = "Day 1" or visit = "Screening" then delete;
else visit = visit;
run;
```

Now this is where I get stuck. **I need to create a way to compare the count of lbtestcd by accsnnum between the two separate files Lab and Rslt, and I need a way for it to flag the accsnum where there is a difference between Lab and Rslt for the count of lbtestcd.** For example, if Lab has an accsnum A1 that has 5 unique lbtestcd values, and Rslt has the accsnum A1 with 7 unique lbtestcd value, I need that one to be brought to my attention.

I can do a proc freq for each file, but these are large data sets and I don't want to have to compare by hand. Perhaps exporting the count of lbtestcd by accsnum to a variable in a new 3rd dataset for each of the 2 files Lab and Rslt, then creating a variable that is the difference of these two? So that if difference != 0 then I can get a report of those asscnum? Advice in SQL will work too, as I can run that through SAS.

**Edit**
I've used some SQL to get the count of lbtestcd by accsnum for each data set using the code below, though I still need to figure out how to export these values to a data set to compare.

```
proc sql;
select accsnnum, count(lbtestcd)
from work.lab1
group by accsnnum;
quit;

proc sql;
select accsnnum, count(lbtestcd)
from work.rslt1
group by accsnnum;
quit;
```

Thanks for any and all help you can give. This one is really stumping me!

Comment: What are you doing in that first data step?  That is not legal SAS code - can you change it to what you actually used, or let us know what DBMS you're using if it's not SAS in the livingston library?

Comment: Sorry about that -- accidentally cut the wrong bit of code. It's corrected now.

Comment: In SQL, you can use CREATE TABLE to make a dataset with the results of a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do a PROC FREQ on each dataset (or proc whatever-you-like-that-does-counts) and then use PROC COMPARE.  For example:

```
proc freq data=rslt1;
tables accsnnum*ibtestcd/out=rsltcounts;
run;

proc freq data=lab1;
tables accsnnum*ibtestcd/out=labcounts;
run;

proc compare base=lab1 compare=rslt1 out=compares /* options */;
by accsnnum;
run;
```

PROC COMPARE has a lot of options; in this case the most helpful would probably be:

- outnoequal - only outputs rows for each row that are not identical in the two datasets
- outbase and outcomp - outputs a row for each of BASE and COMPARE datasets (if OUTNOEQUAL, then only when they differ)
- outdif - outputs 'difference' rows, ie, one minus the other; this may or may not be helpful for you

The [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146741.htm) lists all of the options.  You may also need to look at the `METHOD` options if your data might have numeric precision issues.

Comment: Proc Compare, while seeming simple, is pretty daunting. Thanks for the explanation.